# uniform size of circles around enumitems

Tags: enumerate

I wished to have an enumerated (lettered) list with the items circled.

In the example below, the sizes of the circles were not uniform:

---

MWE

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}


\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%        
        \node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\newcommand\citem{%
  \stepcounter{enumi}\item[\circled{\alph{enumi}}]}

\newcommand\citemq{%
  \stepcounter{enumi}\item[\circledq{\alph{enumi}}]}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

    \citem try 1
    \citem try 2
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: add a `\strut` before `\alph{enumi}` in the `\cite...` definitions would be one way.  Or, alternately, add `\strut` before `#1` in the `\circled` definition.

Comment: An alternative is using the tikz option `minimum size` and set it to some value big enough to accommodate all the labels

Comment: @Bordaigorl Your suggestion is better than mine.  Why don't you write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it, exploiting

1. `enumitem`'s label definition options
2. `tikz`'s `minimum size` option
3. `\strut`

The code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}


\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
        \node[circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em,inner sep=0] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand\circledalt[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
        \node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {\strut #1};}}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\alph*}]
    \item try 1
    \item try 2
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circledalt{\alph*}]
    \item try 1
    \item try 2
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```